# SharePoint 2010 Farm WSP deployment, one wfe is down

Tags: sharepoint-2010, wsp

I have SharePoint farm 2010 with two wfe's, in which one wfe is down. Can I deploy a wsp solution now? What are the consequences?

Answer (score 0):

You can but why would you want to put your WFE Servers out of sync. Consequence is whenever the server is up and if you have load balancing enabled, than the request can go to other server where you didn't do deployment.

Excerpt from [Installation and Deployment of a Farm Solution in SharePoint 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa544500.aspx)

> It is possible to deploy a solution on only one server even in a multi-server farm, using the DeployLocal property. This should be done only temporarily as a troubleshooting step. At all other times, the front-end web servers should be identically configured.